# WIx CustomAction missing localization folders

Tags: dll, localization, wix, custom-action

I have a problem with a custom action that has a reference to a localized dll(let's call it X.dll). When I build the CA project I can see in bin folder several language folders(de, fr, ...) as it should, each containing X.resources.dll corresponding to that language. The problem appears when I run the setup. When it extracts the CA binaries the language folders are not there; instead I can see only one X.resources.dll file.
I need all of those resources dll to be present or my action will fail.

Does anyone has a clue why this happens and why what's extracted is not the same with what's in the bin folder of the CA project?

The setup is configured to build all cultures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to include more files into the cmd line for makesfxCA.exe. I think you need to define $(CustomActionContents) msbuild property which is a ;-delimited list of paths to files to include.

You can see the msbuild target that is run at the end of your custom action project in the [wix.ca.targets](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/tools/WixTasks/wix.ca.targets) file.

I don't know if this will try to put all the included files in the root path or not so this may cause issues with duplicate name dlls. Alternatively you can figure out how to create one localization dll for all supported languages but this may be difficult (although I'm sure it must be possible).

Comment: I tried adding folders to project file, like 
   <CustomActionContents>$(OutputPath)..\..\de\File.resources.dll;$(OutputPath)..\..\es</CustomActionContents> .
For the first case, File.reosources.dll will be overwrite because another one, in another language exists and in the package there's no directory. 
In the second example I tried to get the folder (es) but it gives an error on build "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied". 
Without including the folders there's no point of including the files because they will overwrite the others.

Comment: That's what I was worried about =/ I actually did a bit of lookin-around and found [this](https://buildmaestro.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/c-dtf-using-locale-net-culture-folder-and-resources-files-for-translations-with-makesfxca-exe/) (<-- hyperlink) which should be exactly what you want!

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is what I expected, except one thing: cmd.exe has a command length limit of 8192 characters. If the files with paths result in a MakeSfx command longer than 8192 characters it will fail with error. I will try to see if I can limit the command length or if I can use an alternative solution like zipping Bin folder, including the zip in the build and then adding to the CA method the extraction of the zip before my actual action. Thanks a lot for finding this solution!

Comment: One important thing for whoever needs to do this: make sure you include CustomAction.config into the post build command, otherwise Sfx will use CLR v2 and not 4, which might result in error.

Answer (score 0):

As Brian Sutherland writes, to make the final CA dll include additional files you can add them to the semicolon separated string defined by `$(CustomActionContents)`.

The build action used to pack the CA dll is called `PackCustomAction`. The additional files needs to be added to the property before that build action.

As noted in [this blog post](https://buildmaestro.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/c-dtf-using-locale-net-culture-folder-and-resources-files-for-translations-with-makesfxca-exe/), to create a target folder structure for the unpacked CA dll you need to add the files with this syntax:

```
<TargetDir>\<TargetFileName>=<SourceDir>\<SourceFileName>
```

Solution example using a separate build target in the custom action project file, that will execute before the PackCustomAction and add a ru\resources.dll file to the CA dll.

```
  <Target Name="AddFilesToCA" BeforeTargets="PackCustomAction">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <CustomActionContents>$(CustomActionContents);ru\resources.dll=$(ProjectDir)..\ResourceProject\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\ru\resources.dll</CustomActionContents>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```